# Lisp - setq and car

Tags: variables, lisp, common-lisp

I would like to do something like this in GCL lisp:

```
(setq (car '(a 1)) (cdr '(a 1)))
```

to get the result of:

```
(setq a 1)
```

Is this, or something like this possible?
Regards, Declan

Comment: Is `a` the name of a variable (lexical o special) already defined? Or it is undefined?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And why not use a hash table instead?

Comment: besides all the other issues, it's `cadr` you want here, not `cdr`.

Comment: Just loose the q (for quote). `set` will do what you want. It's deprecated and will prevent optimization, but it does what you want. Why you want it is another matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Common Lisp has a whole ecosystem and you can compile and do all sorts of things during runtime of a program.

`(setq test value)` was originally just a macro that turned into `(set 'test value)`. `set` has since become deprecated, but I doubt it will ever be removed.

```
(set 'test 'a)
(set test 10)
a ; ==> 10
```

Now, `setq` makes sure you don't forget the little quote since 99,99% of the time you named the variable you wanted and you don't need to debug half the day to look for missing quotes.

Comment: Note that `set` will only work for special variables however.  For instance (without any declarations in the environment) `(let ((x 1)) (set 'x 2) x)` evaluates to `1` but sets the `symbol-value` of `x` to `2`.